# IIS 7.5 Application Pool Identity service account generates millions of authentication requests

Tags: iis-7.5

I have a load balanced pool of 10 IIS 7.5 servers hosting 3 services.  These services run under a single application pool - the identity is set to run as an AD service account.

The problem we're seeing is millions of authentication requests coming from this service account - over 10 million a day.  We are not seeing anywhere near that many connections or user sessions in a single day. The authentication type in IIS is Anonymous and ASP.NET Impersonation.

I'm curious if anyone has any idea why we would see so many authentication requests on the AD DS server.

Thanks in advance.

Update: I'm really more curious about the ADDS logs showing so many auth requests from this service account. Even if there were 1M connections per day, those sessions should get cached.